# How can i implement multi state toggle button in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to make multi a state toggle button like this.
But I have little knowledge of Android UI components.

[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your layout, you can use `LinearLayout` as root view group. Or you can use `RadioGroup`with customized `RadioButton`.
2. Draw its background in [nine-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).
3. Set background to root view group.